# Block type not working

Tags: cms-block, permissions, supee-6788

I cannot insert blocks in the CMS editor in the form

```
{{block type="isfeatured/isfeatured" template="isfeatured/featureblock.phtml"}}
```

The Magento version is 1.9.0.1 patched. The patched were applied through FTP as I have no SSH access.

Now, I know the issue is related to the SUPEE 6788 patch and the block permissions, but I can't understand how. There's an issue on the admin page (even though the patch is applied), as in System > Permissions I have only the Users and Roles options (and not Blocks). Anyway, the table `permission_blocks` in the database has the row with the fields `(block_name, is_allowed)` set to `('isfeatured/isfeatured', 1)`.

The exception.log shows this:

```
exception 'Mage_Core_Exception' with message 'Can't retrieve entity config: admin/permission_block' in C:\xampp\htdocs\devsite\app\Mage.php:595
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 2):

You need to give the permission for your block

Go to `System->Permissions->Blocks`.

Click add new block where block name `isfeatured/isfeatured` and `isAllowed -> Yes`

Now save. Clear cache. 
Hope  this will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks for the answer. As I said, it shouldn't be that the problem, or at least not directly. I have no System->Permissions->Blocks option in the admin, but the permission_block row is in the database

Answer (score 1):

***I realize this question is almost a year old, but it was bumped by SO and I think there is some value to debugging this type of problem for others.***

Is your `exception.log` showing that error consistently? If so, then you probably have a bad-patched state of application. I say that because, unless it's related to cache not having been cleared, then Magento will throw that error when the owning module's `config.xml` does not declare mapped table names.

Here's an excerpt from the SUPEE-6788 patch:

```
diff --git app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
index 8446743..6097329 100644
--- app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
+++ app/code/core/Mage/Admin/etc/config.xml
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@
 <config>
     <modules>
         <Mage_Admin>
-            <version>1.6.1.0</version>
+            <version>1.6.1.2</version>
         </Mage_Admin>
     </modules>
     <global>
@@ -50,6 +50,12 @@
                     <rule>
                         <table>admin_rule</table>
                     </rule>
+                    <permission_variable>
+                        <table>permission_variable</table>
+                    </permission_variable>
+                    <permission_block>
+                        <table>permission_block</table>
+                    </permission_block>
                     <assert>
                         <table>admin_assert</table>
                     </assert>
```

Notice the addition of entity config `<permission_block>`. **Is this information present in your instance? That would be the first place to check.**

To understand the whitelisting process, see later in the same patch, the following:

```
...
@@ -160,8 +168,10 @@ class Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template_Filter extends Varien_Filter_Template
         $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();

         if (isset($blockParameters['type'])) {
-            $type = $blockParameters['type'];
-            $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
+            if ($this->_permissionBlock->isTypeAllowed($blockParameters['type'])) {
+                $type = $blockParameters['type'];
+                $block = $layout->createBlock($type, null, $blockParameters);
+            }
         } elseif (isset($blockParameters['id'])) {
...
```

The inner `if` condition only lets the block initialize if the permission manager can verify its type.

Answer (score 0):

My Static Blocks aren't displaying in my cms pages when I add them to the content tab with

> {{block type=”cms/block” block_id=”product_view_block_3”}}

BUT it's not showing. Apparently I have to add the Static Block I want to use however my Admin Interface isn't working because of a Theme I use that I have ALWAYS had issues with SO I can't get into permissions because it's just a blank screen

**Responsive Admin Template by CMSMART** if anyone is interested (It **REALLY SUCKS**)
We are just waiting to upgrade to Magento 2 so we can ditch the Admin Theme WITH EXTREME PREJUDICE ... but I digress

Anyway
I've found the permission list in the Database BUT I can't find the name of my static block - this would normally be added by the Magento Admin Interface
SO
How can I add it manually (My static block identifier is product_view_block_3)
I tried 'product_view_block_3/view' but nothing happened....have I got the 'block_name' wrong?